# Hide dataLabels at specific chart width in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to use javascript so that when the chart is sized below a certain threshold, the datalabels are hidden.  I have the dataLabels initiated in an array of series'. Here's a snippet from the array.

```
 {
    name: 'Muni floaters',
    color: '#009fdf',
    data: [355.000],
    id: 'columnText',
    dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        inside: true,
        //align: 'right',
        x: 135,
        format: '<b>{series.name}</b>',
        color: '#009fdf',
        style: {
            fontSize: '12px'
        }
    }
}, {
    name: 'Bank loans',
    color: '#004b87',
    data: [622.955],
    id: 'columnText',
    dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        inside: true,
        //align: 'left',
        x: -130,
        format: '<b>{series.name}</b>',
        color: '#004b87',
        style: {
            fontSize: '12px',
        }
    }
}
```

I tried the following javascript to disable the series dataLabels but only received errors.

```
function responsiveText(){

    if ($('#container').width() < 578){
        var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
        var options = chart.options;
        options.series.dataLabels.enabled = false;
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    }
    else{
        var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
        var options = chart.options;
        options.series.dataLabels.enabled = true;
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    }


}

$( window ).resize(function() {

    responsiveText();

});
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not attempt to re-init the chart with:

```
chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
```

Instead use the series [update](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.update) method.

```
function responsiveText(){

    Highcharts.charts[0].series[0].update({
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: !($('#container').width() < 578)
        }
    }, true);

}
```

Fiddle demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nMKX8/1/).